# Under which conditions is human energy consumption minimized?

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology, bioenergetics, energy, energy-metabolism

Including but not limited to:

- body state

  - consumed food composition
  - state of the digestive tract
  - diseases
  - wounds
  - sleep
  - coma, etc.; death **excluded**
- environment state

  - temperature
  - light
  - pressure, etc.

Merely curious. I do not expect to find complete answers, which seems impossible, but all insight is appretiated.

Comment: Hi there, I see you're new here, please check out the biology help center (https://biology.stackexchange.com/help) to find out what types of questions are supposed to be asked in the Biology Stack Exchange and edit your question accordingly (https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).
You have an interesting question, just needs some adjusting for this site. Feel free to separate this question into multiple questions after reading the links provided.

Comment: come in a warm environment sounds like the most likely factor. light and pressure are negligable. people that are starving also conserve lots of energy.

Comment: @com.prehensible Thank you for the insight. I am unsure however what exactly do you mean by your first statement; could you please explain?

Comment: coma, sounds like a pretty low energy state, in a warm environment!